# Copy a file into multiple folders, not subfolders batch

Tags: file, for-loop, batch-file, copy

Looking for a batch file that would copy a file into multiple folders (within the same directory that the batch file was placed), but not their subfolders.

For example:
I need `K:\NewCustomers\NewPartNumber.Bat` to go into `K:\NewCustomers\Customer Name\`
but not any subfolder of `\Customer Name\`, there being 200-300 "Customer Name" folders.

I was using:

```
for /R "K:\NewCustomers\" %%a in (.) do copy "K:\NewCustomers\NewPartNumber.bat" "%%a"
```

But this is recursive, and now that there are folders inside of these other folders, I can't run this command without putting it in every subfolder.

I tried running a `for /d` loop:

```
for /d "K:\NewCustomers\" %%a in (.) do copy "K:\NewCustomers\NewPartNumber.bat" "%%a"
```

but was unsuccessful at the syntax and after a while now of looking some things up and trying different things, I'm trying to pull my hair out looking for an answer. I get this error:

> `K:\NewCustomers* was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `for /d` to loop through folders in a non-recursive fashion indeed the right way to go, but you need to use it like this:

```
for /d %%a in ("K:\NewCustomers\*") do copy "K:\NewCustomers\NewPartNumber.bat" "%%a"
```

Alternatively, you can use a `for /f` loop in combination with `dir`:

```
@echo off
pushd "K:\NewCustomers"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /A:D /B') do copy "NewPartNumber.bat" "%%a"
popd
```

Personally, I prefer the first method more, though.

Comment: thank you, sorry for the slow response, but was much appreciated!